# Behaviour of queries in Lucene 5

Tags: lucene

Suppose I have a simple Lucene index. It has only a document, with a field, say "text", with a value, say "maschio". All I want is to create a query that matches this filed like an ending % as in SQL.
The following queries works for me:

```
text:m*
text:ma*
text:maschi*
```

but the query:

```
text:maschio*
```

does not match the document with that field. There is another way to perform this kind of search, maybe using a precise type of query? I need all of previous query to match the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely this is an analysis issue.  Your queries will work just fine using either `StandardAnalyzer` or `EnglishAnalyzer`.  You're profile says you are from Italy, so I'll go out on a limb and say, *maybe* you're using `ItalianAnalyzer`?

The main difference between `StandardAnalyzer` and any of the language-specific analyzers is stemming.  Basically, this means it attempts to reduce each word to a common stem that many different forms or conjugations of the word can all be reduced to.

For example, in English, "play", "plays" and "playing" are all indexed as "plai", so anytime you search for any one of them, you'll get hits on all three.

However, when you introduce a wildcard, analysis gets skipped.

It looks like the stem in your index is "maschi", so the terms up to that point work just fine, but since the last letter has been removed by the stemmer, you don't get a match on it.  If you're query didn't have the wildcard, it would be analyzed as normal, and the problem disappears.

If you don't want stemming in your index, you can just switch to `StandardAnalyzer`.  It's designed to be multi-lingual, and mostly you'll just lose the stemmer.

Comment: Yes, I'm Italian! I've done some trials on a dummy project, and I've obtained the same result I'm asking for using ItalianAnalyzer and switching my fields from TextField to StringField. Another option was to stem my term with analyzer before apply wildcard query, but I can't find how to do it in Java with Lucene. However, which one of these, including your advice, seems to be the best option, according to you?

Comment: `StringField` skips tokenization entirely, which will usually result in bigger problems, for full text.  Attempting to stem the word first then apply the wildcard is possible, but won't solve all your problems.  In English, play becomes plai, but player is unstemmed, so if you did that play* would not match player.  Stemmers aren't really designed to play nice with wildcards.  I'd use `StandardAnalyzer` instead.  You can always use different analysis strategies on the same content in two different fields ("content", and "content_stemmed", or some such).